# Как загрузить в Google Play Market приложение, использующее json?

Tags: java, android, json, google-play, apk

Создал apk файл, вместе с ним, в папке release был создан файл с расширением json. Как мне это всё загружать в Google Play Market, чтобы оно работало корректно?
Нужно ли загружать оба файла и, если да, то каким образом?

Comment: Что в этом файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что изначально был выбран не тот пункт, нужно сделать, как на скриншоте, тогда всё заработает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]